# Is this "classical model of the photon" real?

Tags: photons

I do not know how to phrase the question better but [this article](https://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2015/02/23/maxwell/) claims to have a  classical model of the photon. Has this (rather extraordinary) claim been verified?

Here is an extract from the link above:

> Today Robert Brady and I unveil just such a model. It turns out that the solution was almost in plain sight, in James Clerk Maxwell’s 1861 paper On Phyiscal Lines of Force in which he derived Maxwell’s equations, on the assumption that magnetic lines of force were vortices in a fluid. Updating this with modern knowledge of quantised magnetic flux, we show that if you model a flux tube as a phase vortex in an inviscid compressible fluid, then wavepackets sent down this vortex obey Maxwell’s equations to first order; that they can have linear or circular polarisation; and that the correlation measured between the polarisation of two cogenerated wavepackets is exactly the same as is predicted by quantum mechanics and measured in the Bell tests.

The article is talking about the paper at [arXiv.1502.05926](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05926).

Comment: Given that the preprint has a February 2015 date, there hasn't been much time for anyone to do anything with it...

Comment: There is a simpler way for showing that photons (in vacuum only) have a classical model, see my explanations in [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154510/wave-particle-duality-as-result-of-taking-different-limits-of-a-qft/155082#155082)