# Photograph of Light as Wave and Particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction

what is this? actually its the first photo of light as wave and a particle.
[image: here is the photo]

The bottom "slice" of the image shows the particles, while the top image shows light as a wave.

i have questions

1.how this experiment was conducted. Explain it briefly.

2.how this proves the duality.

3.how does this ripples show the duality nature of light.

Comment: It isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Where did you get this picture?

Comment: seems to be [from here](http://phys.org/news/2015-03-particle.html). For that matter seems to be already [asked here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167948/)

Comment: to quote the answer on the linked question: "What they actually measured was not particle behavior. It was just a quantized energy transfer to the probing electrons. That corresponds to the absorption of individual photons, but it doesn't mean the Surface Plasmon Polariton (SPP) field was acting as a particle."; and from the same [an article explaining it](http://www.insidescience.org/blog/2015/03/13/no-you-cannot-catch-individual-photon-acting-simultaneously-pure-particle-and-wave)

Comment: That's a pretty computer graphic... but where are the particles? I don't see any balls in here, just colored pixels.